# Why does this code loop past 100?

Tags: python, random

I am running this code in PYTHON from a Youtube video; its supposed to stop looping at 100, yet it goes above.  Anyone know where the error might be?

```
import random

sarge_is_awake = True
count = 0

while sarge_is_awake:
    print "Down!"
    print "Up!"
    count = count + 1
    print str(count) + " done"

    if random.randrange (0, 100) == 0:
        sarge_is_awake = False
```

Comment: What language is that, Python? Please edit your question and add the appropriate language tag. Thank you!

Comment: could you indent the code ? also it might be because of the random ... it will stop at some random point

Comment: That's how the code is indented.  #TJ Crowder mentioned a counter; how would I do this?  How would this fit into the code?  I have changed line 9 back to 'count += 1'; however, this has no affect.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange), `randrange` will return a number in the given range. It says *nothing* about not returning the same number twice, so your code will keep looping until it randomly happens to return `0`, which could take one loop, or 100, or 200, or...

If you want to stop after 100 loops, you'll need to introduce a counter.

Comment: Pff.. determinism is for wimps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make this loop a random number of times in the range 0 to 100 you'd want something like

```
import random

count = 0
desired_count = random.randrange (0, 100)

print "desired count=" + str(desired_count)

while count < desired_count:
    print "Down!"
    print "Up!"
    count = count + 1
    print str(count) + " done"
```

Note that this may print nothing if the random number chosen is zero. If you always want it to go through the loop at least once you might want to change the range to (1, 100).

Comment: Thank you Bob Jarvis, your code worked once I added the missing colon on line 9!  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Bob, learning this stuff is proving to be challenging to say the least.  I have made much worse mistakes!!